# Bayesian networks in scikit-learn?

Tags: bayesian-networks

I am trying to understand and use [Bayesian Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network). I see that there are many references to Bayes in [scikit-learn API](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html), such as Naive Bayes, Bayesian regression, BayesianGaussianMixture etc. On searching for python packages for Bayesian network I find [bayespy](https://pypi.org/project/bayespy/) and pgmpy.

Is it possible to work on Bayesian networks in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to understand and use Bayesian networks, you can try [OpenMarkov](http://www.openmarkov.org/), an open-source tool. I recommend you having a look at its [tutorial](http://www.openmarkov.org/docs/tutorial).

Comment: Thanks for a good link. Pl see my question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41747/undestanding-bayesian-network-with-openmarkov

Answer (score 2):

[PyMC3](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3) is a Python library build on top of Theano. And then there [pymc3_models](https://pymc3-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#quick-intro-to-pymc3) that adds a `scikit-learn` like API.