# Undestanding Bayesian network with OpenMarkov

Tags: bayesian-networks, markov

I downloaded [OpenMarkov software](http://www.openmarkov.org/users.html) for  `probabilistic graphical models` and tried it on [`mtcars` dataset](https://gist.github.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b).

The `mtcars.csv` data looks like this:

[image]

In `OpenMarkov` GUI, I went to `Tools` > `Learning` and loaded `mtcars.csv` dataset. I then adjusted `preprocessing` settings to have `Discretize` with `Equal width intervals` for all variables.

I then chose `Hill Climbing` algorithm (default) and `Automatic learning` options. On learning, the result was as follows:

[image]

My question is what exactly does this figure represent? Does it represent a `Bayesian network` or some other type of `probabilistic graphical models`? Also, do arrows mean that `hp` affects `cyl` and `carb`; and `cyl` in turn affects `disp` and `carb` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I did not know OpenMarkov. Anyway, from its website it has a particular focus on learning Bayesian networks (Bayes nets). Thus, I assume your figure represents a Bayes net, yes. Syntactically, it also qualifies since it is a directed acyclic graph.

The arrows (edges) represent influences (conditional dependencies) observed in the data.
For instance, the conditional probability distribution of *carb*, **P**(carb | hp,cyl,disp), is defined by the values for *hp,cyl,disp*. However, arrows do not necessarily represent causal relationships.